# .inputrc settings: delete-char and [] keybindings not working

Tags: bash, keyboard-layout, ruby, mingw, inputrc

I am using mingw under windows. When I am using ruby (irb) my 'special' characters like []{} and \ are not working. This is because of my german keyboard, where these keys are used together with AltGr (Alt + Ctrl). I found a solution for this [here](http://www.keyongtech.com/4822896-altgr-keys-and-irb) or [here](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/107774).

Now, when I add the line

```
"\M-[": "["
```

to my .inputrc file the delete-key no longer works. It is defined as usual:

```
"\e[3~": delete-char
```

Pressing delete just returns `[3`, while Ctrl + v, delete returns `^[[3~` as expected.

Somehow these two definitions in .inputrc do not work together. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
It is only the delete key that is not working, my other bindings all work, like:

```
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line              # home (ok)
"\e[2~": paste-from-clipboard           # insert (ok)
"\e[3~": delete-char                    # delete (PROBLEM)
"\e[4~": end-of-line                    # end (ok)
"\e[5~": history-search-backward        # pageup (ok)
"\e[6~": history-search-forward         # pagedown (ok)
```

Comment: For me also the history-search forward and backward are not working.

Answer (score 1):

`DEL: delete-char`

Should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

\M-[ means META-[ which can be done with ALT-[ or ESC,[
\e[ means ESC,[ but that was just redefined previously

Comment: But everything beside the delete key still works - so does the insert key, which is `"\e[2~": ...`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to introduce a [conditional init construct](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Init-Constructs):

```
$if ruby
  "\M-[": "["
  "\M-]": "]"
  "\M-{": "{"
  "\M-}": "}"
  "\M-\\": "\\"
  "\M-|": "|"
  "\M-@": "@"
  "\M-~": "~"
$else
  "\e[1~": beginning-of-line              # home
  "\e[2~": paste-from-clipboard           # insert
  "\e[3~": delete-char                    # delete
  "\e[4~": end-of-line                    # end
  "\e[5~": history-search-backward        # pageup
  "\e[6~": history-search-forward         # pagedown
$endif
```

But the original question: what is happening here still exists :)